# meteor throwing unable to find module for HTML page

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am an newbie for meteor. When i'm trying to import an HTML page, it shows me the error in the terminal stating this.

> Unable to resolve some modules:
>
> "fnoldetail.html"

And the JS is given below

```js
import angular from 'angular';
import angularMeteor from 'angular-meteor';
import template from './fnol.html';
import navCtrl from '../navigation/navigation';
import {Claims} from '../../startup/collection.js';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';

const name="fnolList";

class FnolListCtrl {
  constructor($scope) {
    $scope.viewModel(this);

    this.helpers({
      fnols() {
        return Claims.find({status:'new'});
      }
    })
  }
}

export default angular.module(name, [
  angularMeteor,
  uiRouter,
  navCtrl.name
])
.component(name, {
  templateUrl: 'imports/components/fnol/fnol.html',
  controller: ['$scope', FnolListCtrl]
})
.config(config);

function config($stateProvider) {
  'ngInject';
  $stateProvider
  .state('fnol',{
    url:'/fnol',
    template:'<fnol-list></fnol-list>'
  })
}
```

And in console it shows me this.

```
modules-runtime.js?hash=d3c3e5d67c95f97a60888bda7373292efad3be5e:232 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './fnol.html'
at makeMissingError (modules-runtime.js?hash=d3c3e5d67c95f97a60888bda7373292efad3be5e:232)
at Module.require (modules-runtime.js?hash=d3c3e5d67c95f97a60888bda7373292efad3be5e:251)
at Module.moduleLink [as link] (modules.js?hash=373f4b446711c9806553a5aac9a6ac92aa182748:299)
at fnol.js (fnol.js:1)
at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=d3c3e5d67c95f97a60888bda7373292efad3be5e:346)
at Module.require (modules-runtime.js?hash=d3c3e5d67c95f97a60888bda7373292efad3be5e:248)
at Module.moduleLink [as link] (modules.js?hash=373f4b446711c9806553a5aac9a6ac92aa182748:299)
at main.js (main.js:1)
at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=d3c3e5d67c95f97a60888bda7373292efad3be5e:346)
at Module.require (modules-runtime.js?hash=d3c3e5d67c95f97a60888bda7373292efad3be5e:248)
```

Comment: HTML imports have been removed from the custom elements specification, maybe it's that?

Comment: Please add the HTML file content. This error is often thrown when there is faulty HTML involved.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#intro-to-import-export) is the documentation about importing files in meteor.

So, your `html` import will be like below:

```
import './fnol.html';
```

Comment: still the same @Sudheer